# Add second variable in PHP statement

Tags: php

I've got a chunk of code that works fine and it displays a value (based on 1 - 100) as a number. However, I'd like to take that same data and manipulate it so that it's divided by 20.

To clarify, this chunk of code displays a bar based on a percent. So we'll say the value it spits out is 90. Therefore it fills 90% of the bar with a  color.  But I want to alter (or add) this same chunk of code so that it takes that value of 90 and divides it by 20 so that it'll "look" more like a 5 star rating system. The bar will fill 90% of the area, but it'll then output text-based score of 4/5.

But I don't know what other variable to add to this code to make that work.

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
if( get_post_meta($postid, 'RankVideo', true))  {
$meta = get_post_meta($postid, 'RankVideo', true);
$meta = $meta ;
echo '<div class="q_progress_bar"><h6 class="progress_title_holder clear fix" style=""><span   class="progress_title"><h4>Supplements</h4 ></span><span class="progress_number" style="padding:   1px 9px 2px;
font-size: 12.025px;
font-weight: bold;
white-space: nowrap;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #cc0000;
-webkit-border-radius: 9px;
-moz-border-radius: 9px;
border-radius: 9px;"><span>' .   $meta  . '</span>/5</span></h6><div     class="progress_content_outer" style=""><div data-percentage="' .   $meta  . '"   class="progress_content" style="background-color: rgb(154, 228, 10); border-color: rgb(147, 205,   35); width: ' .   $meta  . '%;"></div></div></div>';
 } elseif
```

...

I was thinking of adding this:

`$rating = $rating/20;`

But that didn't work.

Ideas?

Comment: I dont see any reason why `$new_rating = $rating /20`  wouldn't work. Unless `$rating` isnt an integer.

Comment: It wasn't defined in the block of code that I posted - that's where I'm stuck as I don't really know where to define it.

Comment: You are overwriting `$rating` when you do that assignment.  You need another variable to hold the second value.

Comment: Correct. But I don't know where that goes or in what syntax.  If someone can post the lines down to echo' I should be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work...sorta. Just need to syle it. Thank you.